# How to enable "Manage Extensions?"

Tags: joomla, admin

I'm trying to get some extensions enabled on a Joomla 3.6.2 CiviCRM 4.7.11 installation. For some reason the "Manage Extensions" option is missing from the Admin menu. I was able to get to the necessary page by logging into the demo and grabbing the URL for the extensions area, but how do I get it added to the Admin menu? The demo is running Civi 4.6.18, but I wouldn't think this option has been removed in 4.7. Screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On some of our (older but since upgraded) instances the Manage Extensions still shows under Admin > Customise, rather than Admin > System Settings - just in case your is there, but just not where you expect it ;-)

Comment: Yup, that's where ours is (still on 4.4, used to be on 4.2 a couple of years ago)

Comment: Thanks, that's where I found it! It was driving me crazy because I knew I'd seen it before, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

To fix missing menu items you can select Admininister -> Customize Data and Screens -> Navigation Menu (or if that menu item is missing(!) go to a civi page and change the url in your browser to end with `civicrm/admin/menu?reset=1`). You can then add the missing items if you know their url and title.